# Calculate length of line in QGIS 3.22.5 using Python API

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis

A *back in the old days-written* tiny plugin for calculating a field LAENGE in my layer is not working anymore.

I tried to fix it and have this code so far:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer() # for testing via Python-console inside QGIS

distance_measure = QgsDistanceArea()
distance_measure.setEllipsoid('EPSG:7030')
distance_measure.willUseEllipsoid() # for assurance

layer.startEditing()

for f in layer.getFeatures():
    points_list = f.geometry().asPolyline()
    length = distance_measure.measureLine(points_list)
    f['LAENGE'] = round(length,2)
    layer.updateFeature(f)

layer.commitChanges()
```

Unfortunately, it will run but produce NULL-entries in the column where I would expect a float-value.

It feels as if I am misunderstanding a basic point here.

Comment: For me it works fine (tested on a GeoPackage  LineString layer). Are you sure the `LAENGE` field you are calculating is of `Decimal` type?

Comment: Yep, data type is as you requested.
Not working for me. :-( I don't get it, why it works for you, Matt. I am so stuck... Could this be a problem due to , and . for decimal dividers?